# jQuery: Push variables to an array inside an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm working inside of an $.each and want to populate an array with the variables from each item

Size and color are determined by fields grabbed from a select box with value being something along the lines of  **L-Black**  (large & black)

```
var options = [];
var sizes = []; 
$(this).find('option').each( function(){
    var value = $(this).text().split('-');
    var size = value[0].replace("Size ", "");
    var color = value[1];

    if ($.inArray(size, sizes) == -1) {
        sizes.push(size);
    } 

    options.push({s:size, c:color});
});
var po = [];
$.each(options, function(i,v){
    var index = $.inArray(v.s, sizes);
    if (po[index] instanceof Array) {
        po[index].push({colors:[v.c]});
    }else{
        po[index] = [];
        po[index].push({size:v.s, colors:[v.c]});
    }
});

console.log(po);
```

this kind of works, it spits out this

```
Array[2]
    0: Object
        colors: Array[1]
            0: "Black"
        size: "L"
    1: Object
        colors: Array[1]
            0: "White"
```

I would love it to spit out something like

```
Array[2]
    0: "L"
        colors: Array[2]
            0: "Black"
            1: "White"
    1: "M"
        colors: Array[2]
            0: "Black"
            2: "White"
            1: "Blue"
```

So I would be able to take that and do an **$.each** and allow for a "Large: Black, White"

I'm stumped, been working on this for a couple hours and can't wrap my head around it, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I went with a more compact version of the code, but it may not be correct. See if this does anything for you:

```
var opts = [];
$("#form").find('option').each( function(){
    var value = $(this).text().split('-');
    var size = value[0].replace("Size ", "").replace(" ","");
    var color = value[1];
    if (typeof opts[size]=="undefined") {
        opts[size] = [];
    }
    opts[size].push(color);
});
```